# what is the values() that I have seen in various CDI qualifiers in java?

Tags: java, cdi, qualifiers

I have seen various references to `values()` inside `@Qualifier` definitions.
I understand `@Qualifier` to be a tagging system, yet you define them as an interface.

An interface can allow enums, but I don't understand the word `values()` that I've seen in the two unrelated examples I've listed below.

Could you please explain to me the word values() means?

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({FIELD, TYPE, METHOD})
public @interface NumberOfDigits {
    Digits value();
}

public enum Digits {
    TWO,
    EIGHT,
    TEN,
    THIRTEEN
}
```

---

```
package com.byteslounge.bean;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.FIELD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import javax.inject.Qualifier;

@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({FIELD, TYPE, METHOD})
public @interface MessageTransport {

  MessageTransportType value();

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are not interfaces. These are [annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/). It is possible to declare static information on annotations and annotate them. Code that inspects annotations can then utilize this information.

Annotations declared as [Qualifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Qualifier.html)s let CDI [disambiguate between implementations of the same type](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/cdi-inject.html).

Consider the qualifier `Foo`:

```
@Qualifier @Retention(RUNTIME) @Target({FIELD, TYPE, METHOD})
public @interface Foo { int value(); }
```

Types annotated with `Foo`:

```
@Foo(1) public class Bar implements Runnable {
   //...impl

@Foo(2) public class Baz implements Runnable {
   //...impl
```

A CDI bean:

```
public class Bean {
  @Inject @Foo(1) Runnable a;
  @Inject @Foo(2) Runnable b;
  //...impl
```

Here, `a` will be resolved to an instance of `Bar` while `b` will be resolved to an instance of `Baz`.

Without the qualifier annotation, the CDI API wouldn't be able to tell which instance of `Runnable` to inject. All the values must be an exact match.

Comment: This is all good, but doesn't answer the question. "values" in an annotation (which in the bytcode is actually a special type of interface) is the default name of an annotation member.

Comment: hey thanks so much for this info both of you.  I should have realized that @interface and Interface, are both key words and an annotation.  Wow.  Easy mistake to make there with identical names.  And thanks for the explanation of values.